# how to use django admin Many-to-many field in forms

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

This is my models:

```
class Affiliation(models.Model):
    submission = models.ForeignKey(Submission, related_name='submission_affiliations')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sequence_no = models.CharField('Sequence No.', max_length=1, default='1')

class Author(models.Model):
    submission = models.ForeignKey(Submission, related_name='submission_authors')
    salutation = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    presenting_paper_flag = models.BooleanField("Presenting Paper")
    sequence_no = models.CharField('Sequence No.', max_length=1, choices = SQ_NO, default='1')
    affiliations = models.ManyToManyField(Affiliation, through='AuthorAffiliation')

class AuthorAffiliation(models.Model):
    submission = models.ForeignKey(Submission)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    affiliation = models.ForeignKey(Affiliation)
```

The relation between Affiliation and Author is M2M.
There is "affiliations" field in "Author" class.
There are "author" and "affiliation" in "AuthorAffiliation" class.

**When I go to django admin to add more author, it should be shown like below (please focus on the red oval):**

http://nc7.upanh.com/b5.s1.d1/a68263c1da3310d189ef9252b0f482ef_35227917.screenshot20110916at1.png

**

### I'd like to make the same thing as it in my form, could anybody show me how?

**

**This is my current form:**

http://nc9.upanh.com/b4.s9.d1/851b97ed981502921443ce4d4a614ff0_35228599.screenshot20110916at3.png

Thanks.

(Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you would consider using ajax, but if, [django-ajax-selects](http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-selects/) should help you, I have been using it several times.

Comment: I read it before but it's not what I need to do. I just wanna do exact thing as my first uploaded image.

Answer (score 0):

you can do some like how G-mail does for its "To" field in email composer
there is a text area or text field which has auto complete, and this auto-complete places comma separated values in the text area... 
This will require JS/ajax